# useRef with forwardref

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I know that forwardref can be used to get the reference of dom elements, However, I wonder if I can use it for something like this:

```
const dummy = React.forwardref((props, ref) => {
    ref = useRef("somevalue")
    return(
        <button onClick = {() => ref.current = "somenewvalue"}>
            Click to change ref Value
        </button>
    )
})
```

I need this because, I want things to be changed in the parent based on how the child component is treated.

Comment: This is what state is for. https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Okay, I will search for lifting state up with hooks